# Get host machine name when a script/command is executed powershell Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I have some `Powershell` scripts for deploying our applications to test machine. These have to be executed using `Invoke-Command` from the developer machine. Is there anyway to log host machine name/IP from which these scripts are called. 
For example:
If developer foo deployed an application using the script from `devmachine1` i want to get the name/IP of the `devmachine1` and log it in our test machine.

We are using `Powershell V4.0`. Can upgrade to `5.0` if required.

Comment: Add to the invoke command a argumentlist with the ip and hostname and use them in the scriptblock

Comment: I don't have anywhere to test it right now, but there is automatic variable called $PSSenderInfo that has a .UserInfo property that looks like it might contain what you need without having to manually pass it through. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.remoting.pssenderinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#properties_

Comment: Looks like $PSSenderInfo.ConnectedUser gives you the username of the person who invoked the script remotely but not the originating machine name. If the account used is local though then the machine name might be in that variable.

Comment: thanks guys. I came up with hybrid approach of passing computer name as a parameter and getting the user name using $PSSenderInfo.ConnectedUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering this to mark the question as solved. just incase if some one is looking for an answer.
I am passing computer name `$env:COMPUTERNAME` as a parameter to the remote script.
Getting the remote username using `$PSSenderInfo.ConnectedUser` in the remote script.